# For Delta-Wye transformers, with neither side grounded, can one get electrocuted by standing on earth and touching one of the Delta side wires?

Tags: transformer, power-engineering

It seems to me that there is no path to ground in this case. So, the voltage on the Delta-side of the transformer cannot drive a current through the ground (ie, through the one touching the wire), even with very high voltages. Is this a flawed understanding?

Comment: Capacitive coupling is what you have failed to recognize.

Comment: @Andyaka So, with wires sufficiently far from the earth ground, the capacitance would be low enough to not enable a current to be driven?

Comment: There will always be a small capacitive current.

Comment: @Andyaka Right, but at some distance/insulation from ground, the danger would be negligible. Just like we can have 120V running in our houses without current coupling to us through the air, with a sufficient distance from 1 MV lines, the air resistance would be too large to  enable a dangerous current to flow?

Comment: @CaptainFantastic typical installations, the core is grounded and the low voltage winding is typically wound next to the core. There will be capacitance, and the capacitive unbalance between the winding and core will cause one of the leads to be "hotter" than the other. You would need to test this with an ammeter.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @qrk. Can you elaborate on how the core is grounded? Even in a delta-delta transformer? Many thanks.